# Custom Button JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Here i have an issue with custom button javascript that gives the following Error.

[image]

in the java script i just printed the custom label.

ex.alert('{!$Label.lbltask}');

So what can i do to remove this kind of error and what is the root cause of this particular issue?

Answer (score 2):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=packaging_protected_components.htm&language=en_US

As mentioned in above link and as per error you can't reference protected component in subscriber instance. Try with other labels or may be clone and make your label and reference in script